# Свой движок MySql

Tags: php

Реализовую один сервис на хостинге и мне нужно дать пользователям доступ к
некоторым таблицам MySql БД(разным пользователям разные таблици). Можно конечно самому реализовать интерфейс доступа к бд(что то вроде пользовательской БД для взаимодействия с основной) но не хочу изобретать велосипед. Может есть какие нибудь движки БД, через которые можно такое реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем ясно что вы ищите, вот варианты:

[phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)

[phpminiadmin](http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net/)

[adminer](https://www.adminer.org/)

[sqlbuddy](http://sqlbuddy.com/)

[phpliteadmin](https://www.phpliteadmin.org/)

Comment: phpMyAdmin у меня по умолчанию. adminer тоже пробовал. Мне нужно дать пользователям моего сайта дать доступ к БД. т.е что бы они могли под своими логинами заходить туда и видеть(изменять) только определенные таблици

Comment: @antonin14d не задумывался об этом, но не льзяли создать пользователся с доступом к определёным таблицам в mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: если можно это хорошо. Буду пробовать

Comment: @Naumov верно написал, можно разграничить, если есть доступ. Но задача странная конечно)

Comment: В том же phpmyadmin, на странице редактировании пользователя, можно настроить доступ на уровне баз и таблиц